# Selecting numbers from list in a shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile

I have multiple data points and columns in a shape file format. I am familiar with how to execute my question in Matlab but i want to complete the same thing in R.

In matlab the code would be as follows:

```
tf = x > 0 & x <=500;
z = y(x==1);
```

Basicially i want to highlight certain values of one column and then use those highlighted values to select values of a different column. To do comparative analysis.

Thanks!

Comment: You can ask this [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com), it would be more helpful to you.

Comment: @GokcenG I disagree.  As stated, there's nothing GIS about this question other than the shapefile tag.

Comment: @Ari B. Friedman I didn't say 'he should', I thought people at GIS site could be more familiar with R and shapefiles. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: @GokcenG Fair 'nuff.  I'm always in favor of GIS questions being migrated to gis.SE, so good to see another person out there pushing that :-)

Comment: @Ari B. Friedman, I had asked my questions about GIS here once, after noticing GIS site i saw users there could help a lot more. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Reproducible data would go a long way here.

```
tf <- x > 0 & x <=500
z <- y[x==1]
```

If your data are all vectors, the above will work.  If they're `data.frames`, you should explore the basic, basic R materials available on the internet and you will find the answer very quickly.

I'm pretty sure you mean `data.frame` not `shapefile`.  Shapefiles are complex formats used to store GIS data (land maps).